# How to avoid return in scala

Tags: scala, return, coding-style, return-value, code-cleanup

I have an example like this one:

```
def demo(a: Int, b: Int, c:Int): Int = {
        if (a == 1)
          return 10
        if (b == 2)
          return 20
        if (c == 3)
          return 30
        40
      }
```

The code works well, but I know in Scala we try to avoid the **return**. So I would like to ask there are any different way we can avoid the return?
Thank you

**Edited**
This is the real case I got, and I would like to avoid the return.

```
post("/") {

if (product_id <= 0)
    return BadRequest(Map("ERROR" -> "PRODUCT_ID IS WRONG"))

if (file_id.isEmpty())
    return BadRequest(Map("ERROR" -> "FILE ID NOT FOUND"))

if (data_type.isEmpty())
    return BadRequest(Map("ERROR" -> "FILE TYPE NOT FOUND"))

if (data_type.get != "cvs")
    return BadRequest(Map("ERROR" -> "FILE TYPE IS WRONG"))

OK(Map("SUCCESS" -> "THANK YOU"))
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The basic option would be to use if else:

```
if (a == 1) 10 else if (b == 2) 20 else if (c == 3) 30 else 40
```

Another option is to use pattern matching:

```
def demo(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int): Int = (a, b, c) match {
  case (1, _, _) => 10
  case (_, 2, _) => 20
  case (_, _, 3) => 30
  case _ => 40
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Assaf Mendelson for answering me. Yup, but if I have more than 3 variables, maybe 10, if I use pattern matching, it will be hard for reading. are there any way else?

Comment: If you have 10 variables of the same type it's probably better to pass them as a List, zip this list with indexes and then use pattern matching in more readable way. Like: `case (value,index) => ...`

Comment: IMHO @WilsonHo, if you have many parameters nothing will be more readable than pattern matching or nested `if / else` _(you usually will break each if by line)_ - the Bogdan's suggestion also seems fine. Anyways, if you have many parameters that is probably a [code smell](http://www.scalastyle.org/rules-1.0.0.html#org_scalastyle_scalariform_ParameterNumberChecker) and you may search for a way to refactor it. For example, using a List as suggested.

Comment: @WilsonHo could you provide a more detailed example? There are probably many more options (e.g. pattern matching a list as Bogdan suggested, pattern matching on a map and more), however, to figure out what would make it better, a real code example should be provided.

Comment: Sorry guy about the unclear example, I updated my question.

Comment: @WilsonHo pattern matching or `else if` will be fine in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that, for large number of parameters:

```
def demo(ints: Int*) =
  ints.foldLeft((0, 1, 40)) { (acc, i) =>
      if (acc._2 == i && acc._1 == 0) (1, acc._2, i * 10)
      else (acc._1, acc._2 + 1, acc._3)
    }._3
```

I am not sure it is easy to read, but if you have many arguments maybe it is something to consider. 
Some explanations: In the foldLeft we start with the (0, 1, 40) 0 is an indicator if we found value to return, 1 is an index in ints, and 40 is the result, if found another value to be returned  it will be replaced. If "demo" is just a simple way to explain another problem you have, you should replace the condition and it's result according to your real problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I tried with foldLeft, but that's not what I want